# In Shrek 1, did Fiona think that Lord Farquaad was Prince Charming?

Tags: shrek

When Shrek had rescued Fiona and took off his helmet, Fiona confirmed that she was “expecting Prince Charming” when Shrek asked her,

Shrek told her that he rescued her so Farquaad could marry her and throughout the journey to Duloc, she begins to think that a kiss from Farquaad would break her curse and keep her a permanent human.

So DID she think that Farquaad was Prince Charming?

Comment: I highly doubt it. Prince Charming was her fairy tale ending; the romantic moment she had built up in her head. She was aware that “this isn’t right” so would likely be aware that Farquaad isn’t a, or the, Prince Charming as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific character named Prince Charming was created for Shrek 2; at the time the first film was written, it was a standalone story loosely based on a picture book, and parodying common fairytale tropes. The reference to "Prince Charming" is a throwaway line referring to the common fairytale archetype.

The curse Fiona is under refers to "love's first kiss", not to any particular individual so she is waiting for a suitable handsome stranger to fall in love with. Clearly, Shrek is not who she was expecting, but his description of Lord Farquuad matches her expectations, so she hopes marrying him will lift the curse.